# Adding .edmx connectionString to Azure "Application Settings"

Tags: azure, connection-string, azure-web-app-service

So I am trying to add my connection string to Azure for an Entity Framework Database First edmx file and it's not going so well.

My conn string in Web.Config:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyDatabaseName.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=XXXXXX;persist security info=False;user id=XXXXXX;password=XXXXXXXXX;multipleactiveresultsets=False;connect timeout=30;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My connection string in Azure:

```
"metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:MyDatabaseName.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=mydatabase;persist security info=False;user id=**************;password=**************;multipleactiveresultsets=False;connect timeout=30;encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=False;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong... I've looked at 5 posts that tell me to just cut and paste my connection string in there, but they don't mention is leading or trailing quotes are needed... Also not sure that it's going to work for an edmx... I've tried using "custom" also.

Thanks so much for any guidance!!

Comment: Leading and trailing quotes are *definitely not needed*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to configure a connection string directly in the azure portal for the webapp, you have to make sure of 3 things

1) Replace " with single quote (‘) from the original connection
    string that is set in web.config so mine becomes

```
    metadata=res://*/Clash.csdl|res://*/Clash.ssdl|res://*/Clash.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=server.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=db;user id=websiteadmin@server;password=************;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'
```

2)  Make sure that the connection string type is CUSTOM

3) Leave a dummy connection string configuration in the web.config like this

```
<connectionStrings>  <add name="nextgenplusEntities" connectionString="dummy"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

If I remove the dummy connection string then things fail for me….

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The connection string 'nextgenplusEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you SO much!! Worked First Try!!